# working on rollover menu (css) - my menu works well until I want to differentiate the current page

Tags: html, css, menu

So, I'm trying to create a horizontal rollover menu .

Things were fine until I start working on my "current page" to show where the visitor is on the navigation bar.
I wanted to do so with a class named "active".
I want the sub menu to be visible at all time.

It seems like the `<li>` (from my navigation ) which are earlier in the html code than the one with the class "active", doesn't react as they are supposed to when mouse hovered; The sub menu doesn't show anymore...

I'm not sure if I'm clear or if I'm making any sense, It is still a new technology to me and explaining what's going on is quite hard.

Please let me know if you can help me or if you want me to explain differently.

Thanks a lot

Mick

---

### UPDATES

Here are some screenshots of were I am now thanks to Wire42 (I add some lower Z index to the sub menu item as well as a white background).
So now the previous element react properly to the mouse hover but the active element (in the example "take action") doesn't show the sub menu.

[image 1:](http://www.flickr.com/photos/59878563@N06/7631464894/) the active item doesn't show the sub menu (it should show sub menu even when not mouse hovered)

[image 2:](http://www.flickr.com/photos/59878563@N06/7631465756/) problem solved for the mouse hovered items

Am I missing something?

**CSS**

```
#menu_wrapper {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    left:108px;
    top:2px;
}

#menu {
    width:812px;
    height:28px;
    background-color: #B4B4B4;
    padding:0 0 0 60px;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;  
}

#menu li a {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 6px 13px;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;

}

/* get rid of last border in menus*/
#menu li:last-child a, #menu li.active li:last-child a, #menu li:hover li:last-child a{
border:none;
}

#menu li:hover > a {
    background-color: #e9748b;
}

#menu li.active > a {   
    background-color: #e9748b;
}

/*-------------------SUB  MENU---------------*/


#menu li ul {
    display:none;
    padding:0 0 0 60px;
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    padding: 0 0 0 90px;
    left:0; top:28px;
    background:url(Images/background_sub_menu.png) repeat-x;
    width:782px;
    min-height:23px;        
}

#menu li.active > ul{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    padding: 0 0 0 90px;
    left:0; top:28px;
    background:url(Images/background_sub_menu.png) repeat-x;
    width:782px;
    min-height:23px;
    z-index: -1;            
}

#menu li li {
    list-style:none;
}

#menu li li a, #menu li.active li a{
    color:#000000;
    background:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    padding:5px 10px;
    margin:0;
}

#menu li.active li a{
    z-index:-1;
}

#menu li li a:hover  {
    background:none;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #CC6633;
}

#menu li li.active a {
    text-decoration:underline;
    background:none;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #000000;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                      <ul> 
                      <li><a href="#"> </a></li>
                      </ul>
                </li>

                    <li><a href="#">About the Foundation</a>
                     <ul> 
                     <li><a href="#">What we do</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Who we are</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Goals for 2012</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Annual reports</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Help 4 Guys .com</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </li>

                    <li><a href="#">Programs</a>
                     <ul> 
                     <li><a href="#">Male Abuse Awarness Week</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Help 4 Guys .com</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </li>

                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Take Action</a>
                     <ul> 
                     <li><a href="1">Volunteer for PLF</a></li>
                     <li><a href="2">Help our Foundation</a></li>
                     <li class="active"><a href="3">Donate</a></li>
                     <li><a href="4">FAQ</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </li>

                    <li><a href="#">Find Support</a>
                     <ul> 
                     <li><a href="#">Child Abuse FAQ</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Find Support Near You</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Support for the Families</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Our Network</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </li>

                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                     <ul> 
                     <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                     </ul>
                </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: hi, Can u upload screen shot what exactly going at your side? so I can fixed it quickly.?

Comment: I [pasted your code into jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uWpdy/). It looks like the problem is the `active` class sub-menu displays at all times, even when you are hovering over other top-level menu items. Is that your problem?

It would also help if you could clean up your code to make it a simpler test case. For example, the menu item could be called "Active Tab" rather than "Programs."

Comment: Oh, I think I see the other problem, the one that is causing the other menus to behave erratically. I "fixed" it by placing the sub-menu below the other menus with a z-index of -1. There must be a better way.

Comment: You can easily achieve this by using jquery, By removing the active class from Ul and li when it would hovers menu list..  check my below answer.

Comment: By the way, the formatting is *awful*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using purely CSS, no javascript:
http://jsfiddle.net/nammp/1/

This code does two things (which, as I answer this, are hacked in there, but I will go back and clean it up if someone else doesn't get to it first):

1. Active elements receive a `z-index` of -1 and so are rendered under the hover elements
2. Hover elements get a white `background-color` so they visually hide the active elements

I think this solves the problem. Hopefully we can clean up this question so the code is a little more generic.

Comment: That's great, I tried the same thing but if a previous main-level link was hovered, the current one would stay over-top (so I gave up). Well done!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

I apologize for my awful formatting. I'm still learning and I will take example of other formatings to write it better.

The solution proposed by Wire 42 solved a part of the problem but now, the submenu for the active element from the menu doesn't show anymore?

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Mick

Comment: The second line showing the active sub-menu has to be replaced when hovering over other top-level menu elements. I think showing both the active sub-menu and another sub-menu would be a bad idea conceptually. You could show a breadcrumb trail elsewhere on the page. Or do you mean the background image for the sub-menu is missing in my code? Obviously I don't have access to your background image so I just made the background color white instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
What I'm trying to do is when people are on the "take action" page, it should show "take action" in pink (current tab in the menu) and also show the sub menu related to this page (only one sub menu shown).

right now, the submenu of the active "page doesn't show nor does the mouse hover action (over "take action").

Comment: If my code is working in the jsFiddle (and please tell me if it is not) that's all I can guarantee. I can't help you debug your website. I suspect the `z-index` value is the problem. Perhaps you have another `z-index` on your page? You may also want to try implementing the jQuery version offered by Abhishek, below. That might be more robust.

Comment: I'm gonna try to check for the z index. I won't give up on such small thing!!!! Thanks for your help, I'll update with the live website once I fixed it. best. mikael

Answer (score 0):

I changed UL li menu with working sample.
please look into the link. http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekbhalani/ZzF6S/

Let me know if any issue.
 
 
 
Refer below urls, I think it would be useful for you.
[Tab changes on Mouseover](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/mouseover.html) 
[simple css hover tab thingy](http://superfluousbanter.org/projects/demos/simple-css-hover-tab-thingy/)  
 
 
Thanks 
Abhishek

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not too familiar with JQuery but if I can't get the css to work I'll use your solution. thanks. Mikael

Comment: @moretmickael Thanks man. You will use jquery in your website later.